# Get upper triangle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, triangular

I want to get the upper triangle from a matrix. MATLAB have the functions `tril` and `triu`, unfortunately they give the wrong triangle. I'm looking for following triangle, is there a command for it or must it be a loop? If so, how does it look?

```
test=[1 1 1; 1 1 0; 1 0 0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it manually. There are several approaches:

1. Use [`flipud`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) to flip vertically before and after applying `tril`:

   ```
   M = magic(3); % example matrix
   result = flipud(tril(flipud(M)));
   ```
2. Use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create the appropriate mask:

   ```
   M = magic(3); % example matrix
   result = M .* (bsxfun(@plus, (1:size(M,1)).', 1:size(M,2)) <= size(M,1)+1);
   ```

Any of the above gives

```
>> M
M =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
>> result
result =
     8     1     6
     3     5     0
     4     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope this will be developed in future versions.